# XHR request to PHP

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

Hi i am having problems with an XHR post request.

in javascript:

```
self.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
self.xhr.setRequestHeader("Method", "POST " + url + " HTTP/1.1");
```

In firebug:

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
{"u":"andrepadez","m":"\n...    
JSON    
m
    "sfdsfsdfdsfdsf"    
u
    "andrepadez"
Source
{"u":"andrepadez","m":"\nsfdsfsdfdsfdsf"}
```

In .NET, I post this to an .ASHX, and in the ProcessRequest i do:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream, context.Request.ContentEncoding);
javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(message);
```

and I have no problems.

I don't know how to get the data in PHP, either $_POST and $_REQUEST are empty arrays.

Any help please?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not set a field name for the data being sent. PHP requires data coming in via POST to be in a `fieldname=value` format. _POST is an array like any other, and every value stored in a PHP array must have a key (which is the form field name).

You can try retrieving the data by reading from php://input:

```
$post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

But the simplest solution is to provide a fieldname in your XHR call.

Comment: thank you very much... i can't use the first answer (at least right away) because i am implementing a colleague's code but the second one works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but you are setting the content to json. I'm guessing this is confusing your PHP webserver. Try setting your POST contents to what you tell the server it will be (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) or read the raw HTTP contents in `php://input`.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then naturally PHP will want to parse the POST body. But as the data does not actually constitute form data, it is discarded as invalid.

You need to set the correct CT `application/json` (actually doesn't matter) so PHP will leave it alone. Then it becomes available as [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) or [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)